# How to use viewmodel in recyclerview adapter

Tags: android, mvvm, android-databinding

I am creating Recyclerview using MVVM and data binding. Now I need to perform some network operation in Recycler view adapter. So how can we create ViewModel and Live data for adapter. How can adapter observe live data.

I have create ViewModel using activity context and but not working proper

```
class CartAdapter(cartList: ArrayList<ProductData>, context: BaseActivity) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<CartAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {

    private val itemList = cartList
    private val activity = context
    private var viewModel: CartAdapterViewModel =
        ViewModelProvider(context).get(CartAdapterViewModel::class.java)

    init {
        initObserver()
    }


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
        val view =
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.cart_item_layout, parent, false)
        return MyViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val item = itemList[position]
        holder.setData(item)

        }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return itemList.size
    }

    class MyViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        var binding: CartItemLayoutBinding? = DataBindingUtil.bind(itemView)


        fun setData(model: ProductData) {
            binding?.item = model

        }
    }

    private fun initObserver() {
        viewModel.statusResponse.observe(activity, {
            activity.hideLoader()
            
        })

        viewModel.serverError.observe(activity, {
            activity.hideLoader()
        })
    }

}
```

Comment: `Now I need to perform some network operation in Recycler view adapter.` this already sounds like a bad idea..

Comment: @ a_local_nobody actually I perform some action in cart list like increase cart item, decrease cart item, delete cart item, so i need network call on adapter. If you have any better suggestion to perform this action or what is standard way, please suggest

Comment: you should make use of callbacks to move these operations back to your activity/fragment

Comment: @ a_local_nobody I want to write code of network operation in viewmodel class not in adapter class, so i want to know that can we create separate viewmodel for adapter class.

Comment: you add callbacks to your adapter so that it tells your activity or fragment what to do, then you can execute the service call (from your activity/fragment) using your view model and finally notify the adapter and your fragment/activity of the result. that's how mvvm is done, not really by using a vm inside an adapter

Answer (score 2):

You should not create a separate `ViewModel` for adapter.

**The Classic way:**

The adapter should expose an interface whose implementation would later handle e.g. clicks on an item in the `RecyclerView`.

```kotlin
class CartAdapter(
    cartList: ArrayList<ProductData>,
    private val itemClickListener: ItemClickListener // This is the interface implementation
    // that will be provided for an item click in this example
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<CartAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {

    interface ItemClickListener {
        fun onItemClick(position: Int)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ScanResultViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.binding.root.setOnClickListener {
            itemClickListener.onItemClick(position)
        }
    }

    // this function would be useful for retrieving an item from the recyclerview
    fun getItemAt(position: Int): ProductData = itemList[position]
    ...
}
```

Later on when instantiating the `CartAdapter` in Your `Activity` or `Fragment` You would have to provide that interface implementation:

```kotlin
private val cartAdapter: CartAdapter = CartAdapter(
        cartList,
        object : CartAdapter.ItemClickListener {
            override fun onItemClick(position: Int) {
                // this function will handle the item click on a provided position
                doSomethingWithARecyclerViewItemFrom(position)
            }
        }
    )

private fun doSomethingWithARecyclerViewItemFrom(position: Int) {
    // get the adapter item from the position
    val item = cartAdapter.getItemAt(position)
    // later on You can use that item to make something usefull with Your ViewModel of an activity/fragment
    ...
}
```

This way the `Adapter` doesn't have to have any `ViewModel`s - the corresponding actions on `RecyclerView` items can be handled by the `Activity` view model.

In my example this action is an *item click* but for a more specific action, You would have to update Your question with those details.

**The more compact way:**

You can implement the same functionality as above using even more compact and neat way by using `function types`:

```kotlin
class CartAdapter(
    cartList: ArrayList<ProductData>,
    private val itemClickListener: (productData: ProductData) -> Unit // notice here
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<CartAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ScanResultViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.binding.root.setOnClickListener {
            itemClickListener(position) // slight change here also
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is using constructor to pass viewModel instance.
Without concerns of unhandled instance scope problem anyway.

Have a happy day.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30928571)